# Parse pushnotificaton not displaying in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I have configured parse and send pushnotification form there (both plain text and json)

then inside my project this methode get called

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }

    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    NSLog(@"----notify-->%@",userInfo);

sharedManager=[Mymanager sharedManager];

THNotificationData *newNotification=[[THNotificationData alloc] init];
newNotification.notificationDetails = [userInfo objectForKey:@"description"];
NSLog(@"%@",[userInfo objectForKey:@"description"]);
newNotification.notificationTitle = [userInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
newNotification.notificationURL = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];

sharedManager.notificationTitle=[userInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
sharedManager.notificationDetails=[userInfo objectForKey:@"description"];
sharedManager.notificationURL=[userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
newNotification.isRead = NO;
newNotification.timeStamp = timestamp;
[notificationStore addNotificationData:newNotification];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kParseNotificationKey object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

i can see then message in log also but after that i got warning in log

```
"2015-01-07 11:26:08.991 PROJECT[325:35376] Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called."
```

and it didnt showing notification in phone(as a popup or alert).

please help me

Comment: Have you implemented  application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: in app delegate

Comment: yes,i have implemented that,please check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this (Its just an example method):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        NSLog(@"Inactive");
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

        NSLog(@"Background");
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Active");
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: no,but i tried to add this along with my code,but that time i got Mac-O Error so i deleted that code